# How do I get a Nidoking with Sheer Force on X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How do I get a NidoKing with sheer force? I know that I must evolve a Nidorano with hustle into a Nidoking, but how do I get one? I have hatched 5 Nidorans and none of them have the right ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheer Force is a Hidden Ability. To quote [Serebii.net](http://www.serebii.net/xy/hiddenability.shtml):

> Hidden Abilities were introduced within Pokémon Black & White as a means of giving various abilities to older Pokémon and providing a new alternative. Pokémon X & Y continues this, with a few changes. First, **Pokémon in Hordes** and **Pokémon found within Friend Safari** each have a small chance of having their Hidden Ability.
>   (emphasis mine)

As such, you'll need to try Horde Battles or Friend Safari in order to get one with Sheer Force.

If you then want to breed this into another Nidoran, do note that either the mother *or the father* can now pass on their ability (previously it was only the mother). Do note that the chance of passing it on is small.

> The most notable change is that Hidden Abilities, which previous required you to have the mother with the Hidden Ability, can now be bred without the mother having it. If the father has got the Hidden Ability, there is a small chance that the offspring will also have their Hidden Ability. -[Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/breeding.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have to find someone with a Nidorino [Friend Safari](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friend_Safari) who has beaten the Elite 4 or in Route 11 as part of an [Horde Encounter](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Horde_Encounter) for a chance to be able to catch a Nidorino/Nidoran♂ with it's [Hidden Ability](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hidden_Abilities#Hidden_Abilities), Hustle.

Comment: There is no nidorino FS. The only way is with the route 11 horde battles.